# Setting CKEditor toolbar configuration on pageload results in Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, toolbar

I have multiple toolbars defined and the default toolbar is currently `MyToolbar` as defined via `config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';`

But how can I choose any of these configurations on pageload?

I tried `$('#TextBox1').ckeditor(function () { }, { toolbar: 'Basic' });`
As suggested here [Configure the toolbar when the editor is configured through jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962488/configure-the-toolbar-when-the-editor-is-configured-through-jquery)

But that does not override the default MyToolbar. I also tried removing `config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';` but without luck.

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the console, but I don't know why.

I currently have this code which shows a default CKEditor instance:

```
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="ckeditor" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';

    config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [
        { name: 'document', items: ['NewPage', 'Preview'] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
        { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt'] },
        {
            name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak'
                   , 'Iframe']
        },
                '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format'] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote'] },
        { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
        { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', '-', 'About'] }
    ];

    config.toolbar_Full =
    [
        { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
        { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] },
        {
            name: 'forms', items: ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
              'HiddenField']
        },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
        {
            name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv',
            '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']
        },
        { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
        { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
        { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
        { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About'] }
    ];

    config.toolbar_Basic =
    [
        ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'About']
    ];


};
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to inlcude `<script src="adapters/jquery.js"></script>`. As described here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery
It now works.

Comment: That's very strange because you seem to do it correctly. Config passed to the CKEditor creator method has a precedence over the loaded config file. Could you create a sample that shows the issue, because this method definitely works for me?

Comment: Look into the JS console. Your code throws errors. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Reinmar: the only one I see is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line where I call `.ckeditor`, but I fail to see how to solve that, as I'm including the `ckeditor.js` file right before I call that method.

Comment: But do you include the jQuery adapter file? Read more in the [jQuery adapter docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery).